# How to use alphanumeric fields with BETWEEN clause in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, between, alphanumeric, clause

I have a table that contain a field names as mgrs, the value that stored in mgrs fields is like '42SWC227821555' may contain more charachters, and may contain lower case letters. So now i want to search records between two mgrs, so how can i do that? can i convert mgrs value to integer first and then use in between clause?

Comment: Do you have fix pattern of strings in your values?

Comment: no string is different and has different length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `BETWEEN` clause use [`STRCMP(expr1, expr2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) function for string comparison operations:

```
WHERE STRCMP(mgrs, '42SWC227821555') >= 0 AND STRCMP(mgrs, '42SWC227821570') <= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string expressions with BETWEEN comparison.

```
SELECT '42SWC2278215551' BETWEEN '42SWC227821555' AND '42SWd227821555'
-> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I will list some steps, instead of complete answer.

1. Remove all alphabets from you value, means you can have 1 more customized column using function listed on [this link](http://venerableagents.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/mysql-numeric-functions/)
2. Apply your filter on this column.